# //button[@type='submit'] meaning

Tags: selenium, testing

What is the meaning of the following command in selenium?

I tried to create a automatic test cases.Then following: 
`//button[@type='submit']` syntax I saw in selenium tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an [*XPath expression*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath). It means: find a button element *anywhere in the document* having `type` attribute value that equals to `submit`.

Example element matching the expression:

```
<button type="submit">Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an xpath for finding the element. when you inspect the element you will find `button` as Tag. and that Tag should have values `type="submit"`

Comment: I was thought it is an css locator.Thank you Shasak.